# What are good font management programs to use with Dropbox?

Tags: font-management

I wonder if anybody knows a decent solution to manage Fonts over dropbox.
I use FontExplorer Pro. And tried to do something with Symlinks. It's a complete mess.

Does anybody know if other apps like Suitcase Fusion work better than FontExplorer with dropbox?

Comment: You may find the answers to this question helpful: [How to store and use fonts externally on a Mac?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17643/8708)

Answer (score 1):

I use a font management that came with CorelDraw that I vpn into called [Bitstream](http://noscope.com/2004/font-management-solution/).  Ive looked for alternatives but I cannot vouch for anything else other than [Suitcase](http://www.extensis.com/suitcase-fusion-4/whats-new/).  When I was looking for other possibilities I did run across an article by [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/05/25-font-management-tools-reviewed/) covering font management but it was an old article. Hope it helps.